# Where does the one-instance-per-file restriction come from in Jetpack Datastore?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

The Jetpack DataStore documentation [has rules](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#correct_usage) that you must only create one instance *per file* or its functionality will be broken.

This seems like a very unusual restriction to me and I have never seen it elsewhere in Java or Kotlin. How is declaring one instance in each of two different files any different than declaring two instances within the same file if they are not declared within classes? In Kotlin, you generally think of anything declared outside a class as global and we can fluidly move global code between files of the same package with no impact on behavior or how we use the code (except when accessing it from Java code).

Comment: That documentation doesn't talk about *source code files*. It talks about files *in which the data is stored*.

Comment: My theory is that the library uses JVM reflection to get the current class when the factory function is called. From a JVM reflection point of view, the current class would be `FileNameKt.class`. And then the library stores instances in a Map using the classes as keys, so making two in the same file would orphan one of the instances. I don't know the reason it would make sense to do it this way instead of making them global singletons. But if I'm right, then maybe you actually could declare multiple instances within a file if they were declared inside different objects or classes.

Comment: OOOOOHHHHHHHH, this is an aha moment. There are two completely different ways you can interpret the sentence "Never create more than one instance of DataStore for a given file in the same process." and I've taken the one that doesn't make practical sense. And now that I'm looking at it, the word "process" wouldn't make any sense at all the way I was reading it. @Jorn, can you write an answer?

Comment: Glad to help :) I'm not too sure how to make more of an answer than the comment I already did, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jorn explained in the comments, my basic premise is wrong. The documentation is talking about *data* files, not *source* files.

When I read the sentences

> Never create more than one instance of DataStore for a given file in the same process.

and

> Never mix usages of SingleProcessDataStore and MultiProcessDataStore for the same file.

in the documentation linked in my question, I was interpreting "file" as being the source code file where you declare the instance of DataStore. And evidently I was not even paying attention to the word "process" which makes that interpretation nonsensical.

And it makes complete sense why this restriction is necessary. We want only one DataStore instance per data file being represented so it can keep an in-memory cache to make it more performant to work with. Atomic changes with `edit` won't usually have to wait for reading the current data from the file if it is already in memory (and maybe it doesn't even wait for the disk write before returning but I haven't checked). Starting new `data` flow collections will usually be able to return the current snapshot of data as the first item of the flow almost instantly.